# Using Map algebra to "burn" a river into a a landcover map using GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, map-algebra

I have a map of various polygons where each polygon represent the cost of passage for different vegetations (values range from 10-50). I have a separate map of a river, where the river currently has a value of 1 and the rest of the map is "no data" (this has been rasterised using “File” → “Map type conversions”).

Can I use map algebra to "burn" the river into the landcover map, in a way where the new map represents a channel of uniformly low-cost movement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Burning a river into a map of landcover using GRASS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355207/burning-a-river-into-a-map-of-landcover-using-grass)

Answer (score 1):

You can choose one of two possible solutions using GRASS-GIS:

**Vector based:**

Using the module `v.overlay` and its operator parameter "not" you can get the landcover polygons with the river "clipped out". Then patch the clipped landcover together with the river. Finally assign the landcover polygon whatever value is appropriate. Here are the commands (assuming two polygon vectors: "landcover" and "river", where the column "cost_val" contains the cost value)

```
v.overlay ain=landcover bin=river operator="not" output=landcover_clipped
v.patch input=landcover_clipped,river output=landcover_river
v.db.update map=landcover_river column=cost_val value=10 where="cost_val=1"
```

**Raster based**

Typically "map calculator" and "burning in" refer to raster layers. You could choose to convert the polygons to rasters, as follows (you need to choose a suitable raster resolution so that you have, perhaps, a few thousand pixels e-w and n-s):

```
g.region -ap vect=landcover res=<...>
v.to.rast landcover output=landcover use=attr attribute_column=cost_val
v.to.rast river output=river use=val value=10
r.mapcalc "landcover_river = if(isnull(river), landcover, river)"
# If necessary, convert back to polygons
r.to.vect landcover_river type=area output=landcover_river column=cost_val
```

HTH